# how do I migrate liferay from one server to another?

Tags: centos, liferay

I'm trying to migrate liferay to another server (both are linux machines, and I'm using the CE bundle with tomcat7).

I moved over the entire folder. This is not enough, because usernames/passwords are no longer available. What else do I need to copy over?

I guess it is related to the database, but I thought it'd be inside liferay folder.